# Semantic-ui removing column card height in css

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Hi using semantic ui in my front end and i wanted to make my cards like this [image]  I don't know to do this in my page
the column having the height I wanted to remove the height so that the below card will go upward  '[image]

```
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    align-content: flex-start;
    max-height: 200vh; 
    }


<div class="ten wide column">
    <div class="ui stackable three column grid">
    <%if(post === 0){%>
    <%}else{%>
        <%post.forEach(function(post){%>
            <div class="column">
            <div class="ui card">
              <div class="small image">
                <img src="<%=post.image%>">
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="ui tiny header"><%=post.title%></div>
                <div class="description">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="extra content">
                <span class="left floated like">
                 <a href="/like/<%=post._id%>" class="activating element" data-title="Total Number of Likes" data-content="<%=post.like%>"><%=post.like%> Like</a>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <a href="/view/<%=post._id%>" class="activating element" data-title="Total Number of Comment" data-content="<%=post.cCount%>" style="margin-left: 10px !important;"><%=post.cCount%> Comment</a>
                </span>
                <span class="right floated eye">
                  <a href="/view/<%=post._id%>" class="activating element" data-title="Total Number of View" data-content="<%=post.visit%>"><%=post.visit%> view</a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <%})%>
    <%}%>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you can post your current code, that would be good.